# Integrated webcam problem on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, usb, vmware, webcam

I just try to get my integrated webcam into my virtual machine Ubuntu 14.04 with VMware workstation. But when I use cheese or everythings else I just have a black screen...

So for the technicals details:

- I have VMware tools installed
- I have connected my camera in removabled device tab into the guest machine
- I have /dev/video0.
- When I launch cheese the light next to the webcam turn on.
- In log I got this :

  ```
  Jul  7 02:13:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 1312.046798] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD (1bcf:2985)
  Jul  7 02:13:02 ubuntu kernel: [ 1312.062020] input: Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:03.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input10
  Jul  7 02:13:02 ubuntu mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:11.0/0000:02:03.0/usb1/1-1"
  Jul  7 02:13:02 ubuntu mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 7 was not an MTP device
  ```

Comment: The symptoms are the same for my skype... A shot in the dark: try `LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so" cheese` --- the library come from the package `libv4l-0:i386`. Probably is not the solution, but well...

Comment: Thanks for the help but is not the solution. Nothing change with LD_PRELOAD